# Is auto-sync really the biggest battery killer?

Tags: sync, battery, battery-life

I have been digging the archives for eternity to find that `Location Services` and `Auto-sync` (assuming we ignored other factors such as Bluetooth etc -- because my focus is mainly about `auto sync`) are extremely battery hungry.

Although, i manually toggle the switches (GPS, BT etc) based on requirement. I have paid enough heed to notice the battery gain and drain caused by auto sync `enabled` and `disabled`.

I have read somewhere people claiming innocence of autosync. Basically, Their idea is  that it doesn't constantly push all the data from server to my phone and vice-versa. instead, there is a thread meant to ask the server if there's something new (and events are created based on the responses).

So, shed some light on:

1) is `auto sync` really causing  the depression to my battery?

2) what does `auto sync` really do (perhaps a geeky explanation please) ?

3) how many minutes/hours am i actually gaining or losing while leaving it `ON` or `OFF` ?